# Query keys are encoded in URLComponent's url

Tags: swift, nsurlcomponents

I'm using `URLQueryItem` to encode query values but when I pass queries to the `URLComponent` in the `url` property query keys are encoded too.

```
var urlComponents = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)
urlComponents.queryItems = [URLQueryItem]()
for (key,value) in parameters {
    let queryItem = URLQueryItem(name: key,
                                 value: "\(value)".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed))
    urlComponents.queryItems?.append(queryItem)
}
print("URLComponents Query Items:\n \(urlComponents.queryItems)")
print("URLComponents URL:\n \(urlComponents.url)")
```

Output is:

```
URLComponents Query Items:
 Optional([per_page=10, filters[status]=Active])
URLComponents URL:
 Optional(https://example.com/endpoint?per_page=10&filters%5Bstatus%5D=Active)
```

How can this be prevented? I don't want query names be encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the explict `.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)` call - `URLQueryItem` takes care of the encoding.

Comment: It didn't help. Encoding was done on value by the way.

Comment: Oops, sorry, misread that part. AFAIK there's no way you can tell `URLQueryItem` not to percent-encode `[` and `]`, but it also does no harm except maybe visually

Comment: Thanks, in my case, the server cannot read the key if encoded.

Comment: You should give your server folks a stern talking-to, they're violating RFC 3986.

Comment: @LeoDabus sorry? it supposed to be `filters[somethng]`

Comment: @Maysam Even if you use the regular `URL(string:)` initializer it does result in `"https://example.com/endpoint?per_page=10&filters%5Bstatus%5D=Active\n"`. I might be wrong but I don't think you can avoid it.

Comment: Yes, it seems there is no way to avoid it.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0g9sokq9wwlev9o/URL%5Bpercent%5Dencoding.jpg?dl=1

Comment: I have added the same characters to the dropbox file name as you can see above. Same result. You will need to fix the backend